# How to change referenced file in formula using replace function?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'm trying to change what monthly workbook my formulas pull from.

For example, one of my formulas is `=C3-AVERAGE('W:\2021\09 - 2021\[September 2021 Reforecast.xlsx]Current Price Forecast'!F3:Q3)`.
I want to switch from comparing with the September file to October, for instance.

I am trying to use the replace function to replace the *"09 - 2021[September 2021 Reforecast.xlsx]Current Price Forecast"* with the October file within the formula above.

```vb
Sub vsOct()
    
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim ToReplace As String
    Dim Replacement As String
    
    Set MyCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Price Variance").Range("H3") 
    ToReplace = Range("N3").Value
    Replacement = "W:\2021\10 - 2021\[October 2021 Reforecast.xlsx]"
    MyCell.Value = Replace(expression:=MyCell.Value, Find:=ToReplace, Replace:=Replacement)

End Sub
```

The code puts in a hard coded value like 1.913 instead of the formula with the replaced file name.

Comment: If you want to replace _all_ links to that workbook, consider [`Workbook.ChangeLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink)

Comment: @chrisneilsen how would I have it change just the links on that sheet?

Comment: As I said in the comment  _If you want to replace all links to that workbook_.  If you only want to change links on one sheet, you'll have to find another way

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the formula, not the value, right?

```
Sub vsOct()

    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim ToReplace As String, Replacement As String

    Set MyCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Price Variance").Range("H3")

    ToReplace = Range("N3").Value
    Replacement = "W:\2021\10 - 2021\[October 2021 Reforecast.xlsx]"

    MyCell.Formula = Replace(expression:=MyCell.Formula, Find:=ToReplace, Replace:=Replacement)

End Sub
```

There are multiple [range properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)), such as: Value, Value2, Text, Formula, FormulaR1C1

Comment: Correct. I am looking to replace the specific text that is the file destination within the formula. Even when using different range properties it replaces the entire formula with the hard coded value that the present formula is calculating.